# How to set response content type header as Json in web api2?

Tags: angularjs, json, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-web-api2

[image]Hi I am developing one web api2 application with angularjs. I have one login page with POST method. I want to set as response content type header as Json. I am receiving in a text/html format. I have attached required postman screenshot here. [image]

This is my controller code.

```
var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, obj);
                        var newSessionId = new SessionIDManager().CreateSessionID(HttpContext.Current);
                        var cookie = new CookieHeaderValue("session-id", newSessionId);
                        cookie.Expires = DateTimeOffset.Now.AddDays(1);
                        cookie.Domain = Request.RequestUri.Host;
                        cookie.Path = "/";
                        response.Headers.AddCookies(new[] { cookie });
                        //response.Headers.Add("Content-type", "text/json");
                        //response.Headers.Add("Content-type", "application/json");
                        return ResponseMessage(response);
```

May I know where I am supposed to do required changes? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

To make sure that the web api returns json by default you could configure the formatters connected to the HttpConfiguration in the WebApiConfig class as this

```
//First remove the current formatters
config.Formatters.Clear();

//Then add the json formatter
config.Formatters.Add(new JsonMediaTypeFormatter());
```

Comment: Thank you. But still i am getting as text/html. I have added fidler snapshot above.

Comment: @NiranjanGodbole I think the problem then may lay in the way you create the ResponseMessage. Try to create a new HttpResponseMessage instead and attach data to that instead of creating it from the request.

Comment: Thank you. May i get some examples related to it?

Comment: @NiranjanGodbole var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);....then do the same...and finally: return response;

Comment: Okay  var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK,obj); here i cannot pass obj.

Comment: @NiranjanGodbole what is obj? if obj is a string then response.Content = new StringContent(obj,Encoding.UTF8,                                  "application/json");

Comment: object is object of type class.

Comment: @NiranjanGodbole then use: response.Contenet = new ObjectContent

Answer (score 1):

add `content-type` to header of the request

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I tried as above and it is not working. May i know anything I am missing anything above?

Comment: did you try add  `response.ContentType = "application/json";` in controller

Comment: There is no method ContentType  for response. I tried    response.Headers.Add("Content-type", "application/json") and when i put this i am getting 500 Internal Server Error. I have below code in webapiconfig file   config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes
    .Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/json"));. Does this makes any problem?